# Show paragraph and formatting marks in "Office365: Word Online"

Tags: microsoft-word

## Problem

I'm using **Word Online** which is included in the Microsoft 365 packet. I would like to **display paragraph and formatting marks** but I can't find the button to activate this functionality anywhere!

I also checked the official Microsoft help but therefore I need to choose my Word version from a drop down list which doesn't include Word Online.

Other Microsoft Q&A help documents pointed out that I need to click on: *File > Options* but there are no options in Word Online...

## Menu Bars

#### Home

[image: Home menu bar]

In the home menu bar there are these two buttons:

[image: Paragraph alignment]

But they are just responsible for the left-to-right or right-to-left direction of the current paragraph.

#### Layout

[image: Layout menu bar]

#### View

[image: View menu bar]

## Official Microsoft Support

I also tried to contact the Microsoft telephone support but after waiting for 10 minutes the supporter hang up on me after the first 5 seconds of our "conversation"... (and I paid 20 Cents for that call!!!)

I also tried contacting Microsoft support via chat which shows me the following message for over an hour now:

> The next chat will be available in 16 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I can't find the button to activate this functionality anywhere

It's not currently possible:

> The formatting character ¶ is not available in Word online. We suggest you vote for this [Word online uservoice Please add the "Show non-printing characters" Button](https://word.uservoice.com/forums/271331-word-online/suggestions/16927072-please-add-the-show-non-printing-characters-butt).
>
> This is the best way to let related team hear your voice and help to make our products better for your and others.

Source [Office 365 Word Online show formatting characters - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_o365b/office-365-word-online-show-formatting-characters/9be4a3d3-cbe2-4cb4-bdcf-8335831ca3ba)

Comment: Appears to have been now added...